# Display all emotes in server but with spaces

Tags: python-3.x, discord, discord.py

Seems quite easy but I just can't figure it out. I basically have a script that makes the bot list all the emotes of the server, but the problem is it doesn't make spaces which means it won't preview the emotes and it will all be just text and boring as i have alot of emotes, lets use actual emojis as an example ":laughing:" shows . ":laughing::laughing:" should show  but just shows ':laughing::laughing:' as it is instead. This is because there isn't space, how can i fix that in my script? [In this image you can see what i mean](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8KGvj.png)  Now [And then this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8RJo0.png)

```
@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def emotes(ctx, msg: str = None):
    """List all emotes in this server."""
    if msg:
        server, found = client.find_server(msg)
        if not found:
            return await client.send(server)
    else:
        server = ctx.message.server
    emojis = [str(x) for x in server.emojis]
    await client.say("".join(emojis))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose the problem is in absence of a space in the separator string `""`, which you're using for joining `emojis`.

Replace this

```python
await client.say("".join(emojis))
```

By this

```python
await client.say(" ".join(emojis))
```

Comment: Yes, thank you for your help.. that fixes what I was talking but then i just realised after trying as you said, the problem isn't with spaces, it wasn't showing the images because the server had also animated gifs which is why the bot wasn't previewing the images. So it kinda fixed my issue of adding spaces which is also important because i still wanted to add spaces anyway but it won't still preview till the gifs are removed which i don't want ti do as there are many servers using this bot so do you or any one got some more help on how to make the bot preview the gifs too?

Comment: In this case I consider you to ask a separate question and describe your problem more clearly.

Comment: @Unknown did I answer your question? If yes, then accept the answer. If no, then clarify your question.

Answer (score 0):

```py
@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def emotes(ctx, msg: str = None):
    """List all emotes in this server."""
    if msg:
        server, found = client.find_server(msg)
        if not found:
            return await client.send(server)
    else:
        server = ctx.message.server
    emojis = [str(x) for x in server.emojis]
    await client.say(" ".join(emojis))
```

Answer (score -1):

*different account*, turns out it wasn't the spaces as it still didn't work with them, it's because I was using Async, rewrite works well and shows the emotes without having to put spaces